# go to file in eclipse by using location datatype

Tags: eclipse, file, rascal

When clicking on a location type in the output window of eclipse, you can go to that file (location).
I would like to be able to trigger this with a method in rascal.

So to be clear, I have the location of a java method, I would like to trigger eclipse to focus on this file through rascal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `openEditor` in `util::ValueUI`.

First `import util::ValueUI;`, then try

```
openEditor(|project://rascal/src/org/rascalmpl/library/Map.rsc|);
```

and an editor for the `Map` module will open.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `util::Editors` module. It contains an edit function that opens any file you pass it, with the relevant editor, with optional highlights.

Note, that if you have a logical location like `java+method://...` you will have to lookup the actual physical location of the method in the m3 model using `IO:resolveLocation`, and use that. For example:

```
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>resolveLocation(|java+method:///io/usethesource/impulse/language/LanguageRegistry/IMPFileEditorMapping/setTheDefaultEditor(org.eclipse.ui.IEditorDescriptor)|)
loc: |project://impulse/src/io/usethesource/impulse/language/LanguageRegistry.java|(15638,134,<433,8>,<436,9>)
rascal>openEditor(resolveLocation(|java+method:///io/usethesource/impulse/language/LanguageRegistry/IMPFileEditorMapping/setTheDefaultEditor(org.eclipse.ui.IEditorDescriptor)|))
```